# Android tablet camera not working

Tags: android, memory, android-camera

I am developing an application for Android ICS's 7 inch tablet. In application there is use of camera function to capture image. I allocate camera when somebody opens activity and after  work completes camera releases. This is working fine. When I test this thing for 50 times continually with 4~5 frequency of opening and closing activity, application do not respond to application, Neither for in built applications and suddenly screen gets black and I need to restart system again to continue previous work. Why this problem is coming in system? Is any solution. Thanking you for reply.

Comment: are you on about the nexus 7 tablet?

Comment: Yes it is nexus 7 tablet. This is tab-plus Ginger tablet.

Answer (score 0):

It could be to do with the Nexus 7's lack of a back facing camera. This can cause problems as specified [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html)

I can't think of anything else right now. Try adding a stack trace to your answer so we can see what went wrong.